# requestFocusInWindow working on Mac OS but not on Windows OS (Java)

Tags: java, windows, macos, swing, behavior

I have a problem with requestFocusInWindow(). The other day I had some problems with keyinputs and managed to deduct that it had something to do with the component not being focused, hence it never sensed the keyinputs. I got it working on my macbook, but now when I try the code on my PC it's not responding (just as before I added the requestFocusInWindow).

CODE EXAMPLE:

```
class TetrisFrame extends JFrame {

    private Board board;
    private TetrisComponent frame;

    public TetrisFrame(Board board) {
        super("Tetris");
        this.board = board;
        this.frame = new TetrisComponent(board);    
        JComponent.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);    
        JButton close = new JButton("Exit");    
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        menuBar.add(close);    
        close.addActionListener(e -> {
            int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do You want to close the game?\n" + "All progress will be lost!",
                    "Exit game", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });    
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(frame, BorderLayout.CENTER);    
        this.pack();
        this.setSize(frame.getPreferredX(board), frame.getPreferredY(board));
        this.setVisible(true);            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);            
        setFocusable(true);
        frame.requestFocusInWindow();    
    }
}
```

Keyinput functions:

```
    private final Action moveLeft = new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
            board.moveLeft();
        }
    };

    private final Action moveRight = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
            board.moveRight();
        }
    };

    public void setKeyBindings() {
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "moveLeft");
        this.getActionMap().put("moveLeft", moveLeft);

        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "moveRight");
        this.getActionMap().put("moveRight", moveRight);
    }
```

There are some more functions bound to movement but it's these that are not responding!

Thank you :)

Comment: You could over come this by using `getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)`